# Set which property in POCO to display when databinding to drop down

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

If having a List filled with objects of the following type:

```
    public class Person {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Ssn { get; set; }
    }
```

How can one set the value of the property Name to be what's beeing displayed within an ASP.NET DropDown, without setting any properties on the ASP.NET DropDown object? Of course, one way would be to ovveride ToString() on the class Person, but is there any other way to accomplish the same thing?

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

You can create new control derived from DropDown (e.g. DropDownEx), introduce new attributes e.g. `DisplayFieldAttribute`, `ValueFieldAttribute`. Then use `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties` to enumerate properties and analyze attributes for binding them respectively.